# Lomo'instant films come out with a greenish rim

Tags: film, instant-camera, lomo

My Lomo'Instant films come out with a greenish rim around them (see attached picture for reference).

[image: film with greenish rims]

I thought it could be due to some light coming in from somewhere, but I have no idea what could cause such an effect! Maybe it's just a faulty film pack?

Comment: With Lomo you are never sure whether artifacts such as this are a bug or a feature. Strong focus on quality control is not a part of the brand...

Comment: @JindraLacko Your comment should probably be an answer. If it were I would upvote it. Please see: [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871)

Comment: You are right and I was wrong. Having read the linked meta discussion - and having imagined the horror of making mattdm feel grumpy again - I posted a short answer instead of a short comment. I even elaborated on it a little... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Lomo you are never sure whether artifacts such as this are a bug or a feature. Strong focus on quality control is not a part of the brand - in fact it is the opposite, they take pride in randomness and imperfections of their deliberately low tech products.